# Use sed, grep, or awk without perl to replicate positive lookbehind

Tags: json, regex, bash, awk, sed

I need to extract `RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z` from:

```
 {"user":{"id":1325135,"uuid":"134513451","email":"ansdfaha@aol.com","joined_at":"2012-01-01T013:511:124.000Z","username":"testicl","title":"testli","thumb":"https://plex.tv/user/avatar?c=","hasPassword":true,"authToken":"RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z","authentication_token":"RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z","subscription":{"active":false,"status":"Inactive","plan":null,"features":["adaptive_bitrate","collections","photos-metadata-edition","radio","photos-favorites","federated-auth","Android - PiP","publishing_platform","news","kevin-bacon","client-radio-stations","TREBLE-show-features","web_server_dashboard","conan_redirect_qa","conan_redirect_alpha","conan_redirect_beta","transcoder_cache"]},"roles":{"roles":[]},"entitlements":[],"confirmedAt":"2012-01-01T13:31:31.000Z","forumId":23573,"rememberMe":false}}
```

[regex with PCRP works great](https://regexr.com/49sdq)

```
(?<=authToken\":\")(\w+)
```

How can I extract `RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z` using either `awk`, `sed`, or `grep` without positive lookbehind? I don't have perl support.
I'm doing this out of a bash script on an openwrt router.

Comment: That's JSON file format.  Do you have any tool that can parse JSON?

Comment: I'm doing this out of a bash script on an openwrt router, so I don't think so? Trying to keep it as light as possible. I'm a super newb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's/.*"authToken":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 4):

May be you could install `jq` and use it?

```
jq .user.authToken < a.json
"RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z"
```

Comment: To get rid of the quotation marks add option `-r`. `<` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `grep` is fair game

```
grep -Po '(?<=authToken\":\")(\w+)' file
```

---

Note: This needs an extra library, `libpcre`, for `grep`'s native PCRE support.

Comment: That doesn't need Perl?  It's PCRE support in `grep` ... (or does it use Perl?)

Comment: Hmm, I thought PCRE is perl support? I have BusyBox v1.28.4 and grep does not give me the option to put the -P flag.

Comment: I see. Then perhaps it does need Perl for it -- I thought `grep` has that support built in natively, without Perl, but I guess not.

Comment: It does not. It requires a special package for native PCRE support, `libpcre`  `-ash: pcregrep: not found`

Comment: @stinkybummer Ah, of course, that makes sense; it can't depend on Perl but it does need a library. Thanks for finding it out, we learned what extra bit `grep` needs for that :).

Comment: I have pcregrep in my RHEL

Comment: @stack0114106  It appears that they don't have that.  I find on a CentOS7: `pcre`, `pcre2`, and `pcre-devel` (but not the particular `pcregrep` program, only `pcre-config`).

Comment: @zdim.. yes it is there in our Enterprise RHEL 6.1

Comment: @zdim.. thank for looking at 55104792, any other solution to that?.. first time I use ````\B```` !!!

Answer (score 2):

Some linux flavours ships with `pcregrep` where you can use the lookarounds..

Check this

```
$ pcregrep -o '(?<=authToken\":\")(\w+)' json.test 
RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z
$
```

Here is the version in my RHEL.

```
$ pcregrep --version
pcregrep version 7.8 2008-09-05
$
```

Comment: Actually we talked about `pcregrep` in comments and turns out `openwrt` doesn't shipped with it, however `pcregrep` is a good choice when it is supported :)

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution (tested under `openwrt`):

```
awk -F: -v RS=, '$1~/"authToken"/{gsub("\"","",$2);print $2}' file
RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z
```

Or for more precisely matching, use equal `==`:

```
awk -F: -v RS=, '$1=="\"authToken\""{gsub("\"","",$2);print $2}' file
RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z
```

`$1=="\"authToken\""` functionally equals to `$1~/^"authToken"$/` but is a lit bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple :

```
{m,n,g}awk '$!NF = $--NF' FS='^.*authToken[:"]+|["].*$'

RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z
```

more generally, here's a very crude method of splitting key-value pairs out in a usable manner without going through jq or proper decoding of the JSON :

```
 # haven't tested the full JSON spec yet, 
 # but definitely would look strange if it has
 # embedded newlines, or un-decoded unicode escape codes

 mawk '(NF=NF)+gsub("\42:[\42]?","\42\f :: \42")' \
        FS='["][]}]*[,][[{]*["]|([]}]*[,]|^)?[,][[{]*["]' \
       OFS='\42\n -- \42'

 {"user"
         :: "{"id"
                   :: "1325135"
 -- "uuid"
           :: "134513451"
 -- "email"
            :: "ansdfaha@aol.com"
 -- "joined_at"
                :: "2012-01-01T013:511:124.000Z"
 -- "username"
               :: "testicl"
 -- "title"
            :: "testli"
 -- "thumb"
            :: "https://plex.tv/user/avatar?c="
 -- "hasPassword"
                  :: "true"
 -- "authToken"
                :: "RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z"
 -- "authentication_token"
                           :: "RJ3fadfiasdUYBxF6z"
 -- "subscription"
                   :: "{"active"
                                 :: "false"
 -- "status"
             :: "Inactive"
 -- "plan"
           :: "null"
 -- "features"
               :: "["adaptive_bitrate"
 -- "collections"
 -- "photos-metadata-edition"
 -- "radio"
 -- "photos-favorites"
 -- "federated-auth"
 -- "Android - PiP"
 -- "publishing_platform"
 -- "news"
 -- "kevin-bacon"
 -- "client-radio-stations"
 -- "TREBLE-show-features"
 -- "web_server_dashboard"
 -- "conan_redirect_qa"
 -- "conan_redirect_alpha"
 -- "conan_redirect_beta"
 -- "transcoder_cache"
 -- "roles"
            :: "{"roles"
                         :: "[]}"
 -- "entitlements"
                   :: "[]"
 -- "confirmedAt"
                  :: "2012-01-01T13:31:31.000Z"
 -- "forumId"
              :: "23573"
 -- "rememberMe"
                 :: "false}}
```